# R: How to colour samples on a boxplot by their group?

Tags: r, colors, expression, boxplot

I currently have gene expression data in a matrix, arranged by samples in columns, and genes in rows. I have about 300 samples against 30,000 genes.

There first three lines of the data is as such:

```
         Sample1  Sample2  Sample3   Sample4   Sample5
Gene1    6.53845  6.38723  6.41613   6.07901   6.45148
Gene2    6.34303  6.52751  6.48025   6.79185   6.94955
Gene3    6.17286  6.31772  6.44266   6.61777   7.05509
...      ...
```

And so on for up to 30,000 rows, and 300 samples.

I have been able to plot a boxplot of the data using R, but I am now looking to colour the boxplot based on the batches/groups of the sample.

I have a table of the batch information as such.

```
Sample   Batch
Sample1  A
Sample2  A
Sample3  B
Sample4  A
Sample5  C
...      ...
```

And so on for 8 batches. Using R, how should I go about colouring the boxplot based on which batch the sample belongs to? Thanks!

Comment: Something like `boxplot(..., col = as.factor(batch_info_df$Batch))`. Can you please post the code you are using to produce the boxplot?

Comment: Hi there, right now I am simply using the [oligo package's boxplot function](https://rdrr.io/bioc/oligo/man/boxplot.html), where I can simply give my data matrix as an argument as such: 

boxplot(data.matrix,col='red')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the approach could be

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column("Genes") %>%                          #add rownames as column
  gather(Sample, Sample_value, -Genes) %>%                 #convert data to long format from wide format for plotting
  left_join(batch_lookup, by = "Sample") %>%               #join it with lookup table to add 'Batch' column
  ggplot(aes(x=Sample, y=Sample_value, color=Batch)) +     #plot data
    geom_boxplot()
```

which plots

[image]

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Sample1 = c(6.53845, 6.34303, 6.17286), Sample2 = c(6.38723, 
6.52751, 6.31772), Sample3 = c(6.41613, 6.48025, 6.44266), Sample4 = c(6.07901, 
6.79185, 6.61777), Sample5 = c(6.45148, 6.94955, 7.05509)), .Names = c("Sample1", 
"Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene3"))

batch_lookup <- structure(list(Sample = c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", 
"Sample5"), Batch = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "C")), .Names = c("Sample", 
"Batch"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Hi there, this worked perfectly! It is also my first try at using ggplot, so I would just like to know if is there a way to group the batches together in the boxplot? So the first 3 would be Batch A and red and so on.

Comment: I think I am missing something here so could you please be bit more descriptive regarding your followup question? (sorry for the late response!)

Comment: Hi there, no worries. I actually realized it was a silly question really, I wanted to plot the boxplots by batches instead of samples. I simply needed to set "x=Batch" that's all. Thanks for your help!