# R boxplot color not changing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a box-and-whisker plot in R (y-axis # of reads and x-axis of 4 discrete conditions). I'm trying to switch the order in which the discrete conditions appear and to change them from the default white fill to a color of my choosing using the code below. I can get the order to change, but the color continues to stay white. I also have no idea why R cuts off my plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
capture_data = read.csv("tcp_for_r_plots.csv")
p <- ggplot(capture_data, aes(x=Protocol, y=raw_reads)) + geom_boxplot()
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Standard","TD-60","TD-55","TD-50"))
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999","#FFFF00","#33FFFF","#FF33CC"))
```

Attached is the output I keep getting - no color change.[image]

Comment: see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278580/r-how-to-colour-samples-on-a-boxplot-by-their-group)

Answer (score 1):

- **fill color**: You need to add the *fill* option to the *geom_boxplot()* function as shown below (instead of using the scale_fill_manual function):

```
+ geom_boxplot(fill=c("#999999","#FFFF00","#33FFFF","#FF33CC"))
```

- **Order**: the order is based on the alphabetical order of the factor values (Protocol). One solution is to recode the factor levels into the the order you want before running the generating the plot.

Answer (score 0):

```
p <- ggplot(capture_data, aes(x=Protocol, y=raw_reads, fill=Protocol)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Standard","TD-60","TD-55","TD-50")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999","#FFFF00","#33FFFF","#FF33CC"))
```

Comment: The error is to miss the `fill` argument. You should explain that by words, not just code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the colors in "fill" argument in ggplot:

```
p <- ggplot(capture_data, aes(x=Protocol, y=raw_reads)) + geom_boxplot()
```

should be

```
p <- ggplot(capture_data, aes(x=Protocol, y=raw_reads, fill = Protocol)) + geom_boxplot()
```

For example,

```
 ggplot(mtcars, aes(x= as.factor(cyl), y=mpg, fill=as.factor(cyl))) + geom_boxplot()
```

gives me

[image]